connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream - 502 Error
I am using ECS Fargate (Application load balancer) with nginx and I am experiencing 502 Gateway error.
In my cloudwatch log I am seeing this error:
[error] 28#28: *1971 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 132.31.37.77, server: test.company.com, request: "POST /api/customer/signin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://94.246.73.68:80/api/customer/signin", host: "test.company.com", referrer: "https://test.company.com/signin"
This is my nginx.conf:
upstream api {

*This my application load balancer DNS name*
server company-378610035.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com; 

}

server {
        listen       80;
        server_name test.company.com;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

        location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        }
}

PS: I have opened all the required ports in my security groups like 80, 443, 3000, 5000

I found the solution to my question: I use proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000; for location /api and it worked :)
